# Python list assign by value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list Undo and another ap, I want to save every time I modify the ap list a copy on Undo but when I save, for example on Undo[2] what I have done to ap, Undo[1] is the same as Undo[2], it looks like it assign the list ap and not the value of ap. I find a question similar and tried to assign ap[:] so it will make a copy but it didn't.

```
from Functionalitati import *
from Ui import *
from GlobalVr import *
Active = True
NumarApartamente = int(input("Numarul apartamentelor:"))
cntA = 0
while cntA < NumarApartamente:
    ap.append({"gaz":{}, "apa":{}, "electricitate":{}, "canalizare":{}, "altele":{}})
    cntA = cntA + 1
Undo = Undo + ap[ : ]
while Active:
    while True:
        op1 = Umenu()
        if op1 > 6 and op1 < 0:
            print(x,'Nu este o comanda valida')
        else:
            break
    if op1 == 0:
        break
    op2 = Submenu(op1)

    if op1 == 6 and UndoCont > 0:
        UndoCont = UndoCont - 1
        Undo.pop()
        ap = Undo[UndoCont]
        print (Undo)

    elif op1 == 1 and op2 == 1 :
        ap = AddCheltuiala(ap)
        Undo = Undo + ap[ : ]
        UndoCont = UndoCont + 1

    elif op1 == 1 and op2 == 2 :
        ap = ModCheltuiala(ap)
        Undo.append(ap[0:NumarApartamente - 1])
        UndoCont = UndoCont + 1

    elif op1 == 2 and op2 == 1 :
        ap = DelCheltuiala(ap)
        Undo.append(ap[0:NumarApartamente - 1])
        UndoCont = UndoCont + 1

    elif op1 == 2 and op2 == 2 :    
        ap = DelCCheltuiala(ap)
        Undo.append(ap[0:NumarApartamente - 1])
        UndoCont = UndoCont + 1

    elif op1 == 2 and op2 == 3 :
        ap = DelTip(ap,NumarApartamente)
        Undo.append(ap[0:NumarApartamente - 1])
        UndoCont = UndoCont + 1
```

I also tried with append and Undo = Undo + ap[:] as you can see.
Sorry if the code is a little messy.
edit:
I deleted last edit and I want to make it more clear
So I make another piece of code to resume what I want to say

```
from Functionalitati import *
from Ui import *
import datetime
ap = [] #lista principala

UndoCont = 0
nrAp = int(input("Da-ti numarul apartamentelor:"))
Undo = [None] * nrAp
contor = 0
while contor < nrAp:
    ap.append({"gaz":{}, "apa":{}, "electricitate":{}, "canalizare":{}, "altele":{}})
    contor = contor + 1

Undo[0] = ap[:]
print(Undo)
print("space" * 4)
ap[1]["gaz"]["date"] = 100
Undo[1] = ap[:]
print (Undo)
```

the output:

```
Da-ti numarul apartamentelor:2
[[{'gaz': {}, 'canalizare': {}, 'electricitate': {}, 'altele': {}, 'apa': {}}, {'gaz': {}, 'canalizare': {}, 'electricitate': {}, 'altele': {}, 'apa': {}}], None]
spacespacespacespace
[[{'gaz': {}, 'canalizare': {}, 'electricitate': {}, 'altele': {}, 'apa': {}}, {'gaz': {'date': 100}, 'canalizare': {}, 'electricitate': {}, 'altele': {}, 'apa': {}}], [{'gaz': {}, 'canalizare': {}, 'electricitate': {}, 'altele': {}, 'apa': {}}, {'gaz': {'date': 100}, 'canalizare': {}, 'electricitate': {}, 'altele': {}, 'apa': {}}]]
```

why the Undo[0] modify as Undo[1] ?
I tried with Undo.append(list(ap)) and Undo = Undo + list(ap) and same with ap[:] and now I tried to initialize Undo before and same result.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how you want `Undo` to look after adding `ap` and an example of how it looks now?

Comment: ok I edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Solved.I don't really know how it works but I use `copy.deepcopy()` (`copy.copy()` didn't work)